# How do I fix an error SQLite3 :: ConstraintException: NOT NULL with devise in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am implementing an authentication system with devise in rails, but when registering the user, in this case a student, the following error is skipped:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: students.codigo: INSERT INTO "students" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I have been solving this error all day, but nothing that I can solve. I have implemented a before_action in the students_controller controller:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :configure_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user|
      user.permit(:codigo, :documento, :nombres, :apellidos, :es_egresado, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

but still the problem is not solved.
The same error happens when I uninstall devise, remove all reference from it, and also, implement strong params in the controller, without this the registry works satisfactorily. But with strong params and devise does not work, it passes data to null in the SQL command.

The student database is the following:

```
create_table "students", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "codigo", null: false
    t.integer "documento", null: false
    t.string "nombres", null: false
    t.string "apellidos", null: false
    t.integer "es_egresado", null: false
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.decimal "promedio_carrera"
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["documento"], name: "index_students_on_documento", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_students_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_students_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

And its implementation migrate is the following:

```
class DeviseCreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :students, {
      :id => false,
      :primary_key => :codigo
    } do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.integer :codigo, null: false
      t.integer :documento, null: false
      t.string :nombres, null: false
      t.string :apellidos, null: false
      t.integer :es_egresado, null: false

      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      t.decimal :promedio_carrera, null: true

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :students, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :students, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :students, :documento, unique: true
    # add_index :students, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :students, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"6zdENP1iREYYM+qpqtskqRJ+aB38NIX/nG9jFsoGlImqUVyS9bsmBF6Uc7xvDD/J50/zamlZbbm2rwAaCgOmuw==",
 "student"=>
  {"codigo"=>"625762",
   "documento"=>"107526792",
   "nombres"=>"Carlos",
   "apellidos"=>"Garnica",
   "es_egresado"=>"0",
   "email"=>"wcarlosfg.1234567890@hotmail.com",
   "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Registrar"}
```

I also clarify that when I create another Student table, removed the previous one, and I remove the null option to the fields, the error does not appear, but the fields that supposedly have been saved remain in NULL in the database

**UPDATE:** Modify the database, making all fields null, and the form sends null fields whether they have data in the form or not, it is very rare. When doing inspect on the object, it shows the following:

```
irb(main):002:0> Student.last
  Student Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" ORDER BY "students"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Student id: 2, codigo: nil, documento: nil, nombres: nil, apellidos: nil, es_egresado: nil, promedio_carrera: nil, email: "wcarlosfg.1234567890@hotmail.com", created_at: "2018-09-30 07:46:39", updated_at: "2018-09-30 07:46:39">
```

**SOLUTION:** After a day looking at the error, the only solution was to overwrite the devise driver for records, with this, I was able to add the logic and implement strong params to make the registry work correctly.

Comment: Hmm as I can note you are having many fields as not null, and I suppose that you will need to provide the value for all of that fields in process of creating new student? Can you try do add all values in process of creating student?

Comment: Is there a *really* good reason to set the primary key as codigo on that table instead of id?  I would follow this guide to make sure you are setting your primary_key as not being default http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/.  Side thought, how are you

Comment: I have modified the table so that it does not accept nulls, and to leave the ID by default, but even so it has worked correctly